# NavLink always get active class on query

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to add for activeClassName in NavLink.

```
<NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="main-category-item-active"> .... </NavLink>
<NavLink to="/?tab=1" activeClassName="main-category-item-active"> .... </NavLink>
<NavLink to="/?tab=2" activeClassName="main-category-item-active"> .... </NavLink>
```

But the result looks like this picture.

[image]

I think it's because the path is a query.

How Can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [no support](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6268#issuecomment-408450350) for processing query strings React router v4 and up.

Alternatively, you can use a simple wrapper component and use [isActive](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) to determine the activeness-logic.

```js
// simple wrapper component for NavLink
const PathNavLink = (props) => (
  <NavLink isActive={(_, { pathname }) => pathname == props.to} {...props} />
);

// usage
<PathNavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="main-category-item-active"> .... </PathNavLink>
```